# eliminating sub strings from super string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dictionary that has key as a string tuple and value as its frequency
for eg

```
 {('this','is'):2,('some','word'):3....}
```

I need to eliminate some key's that contains those subkey for eg:

```
d={('large','blue'):4,('cute','blue'):3,('large','blue','dog'):2,
  ('cute','blue','dog'):2,('cute','blue','elephant'):1}
```

I need to eliminate `('large','blue')` as it appears only in `'large blue dog'` however I cant remove 'cute blue' because it appears in `'cute blue dog'` and `'cute blue elephant'`

```
d={('large','blue'):4,('cute','blue'):3,('large','blue','dog'):2,
('cute','blue','dog'):2,('cute','blue','elephant'):1}
final_list=[]
for k,v in d.items():
    final_list.append(' '.join(f for f in k))

final_list=sorted(final_list, key=len,reverse=True)
completed=set()
for f in final_list:
    if not completed:
        completed.add(f)
    else:
        if sum(f in s for s in completed)==1:
            continue

print(final_list)
print(completed)
```

But this gives me only ['cute blue elephant'] I need

```
[large blue dog] :2
[cute blue dog]:2
[cute blue elephant]:1
[cute blue]:3
```

Comment: You want to keep the 2-tuples that occur in more than one 3-tuple? I have a solution that loops over the 3s once to build a hashtable and then uses it to check for each 2 if it occurs in more than one 3. I'll write an answer.

Comment: Yes please that’s what I want

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE. If you want the count as well, I'd rather rewrite most of the code to this:

```
d={('large','blue'):4,('cute','blue'):3,('large','blue','dog'):2,
('cute','blue','dog'):2,('cute','blue','elephant'):1}

completed = {}
for k,v in d.items():
     if len([k1 for k1,v1 in d.items() if k != k1 and set(k).issubset(set(k1))]) != 1:
         completed[k] = v

print(completed)
```

Result

> {('cute', 'blue'): 3, ('large', 'blue', 'dog'): 2, ('cute', 'blue', 'dog'): 2, ('cute', 'blue', 'elephant'): 1}

I haven't check the performance though. I'll just leave it to you.

--

How about replacing

```
for f in final_list:
    if not completed:
        completed.add(f)
    else:
        if sum(f in s for s in completed)==1:
            continue
```

with

```
for f in final_list:
    if len([x for x in final_list if f != x and f in x]) != 1:
        completed.add(f)
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: How to also get the count ?

Comment: i have 250000 such segments of varying length. is there a way to improve it? make it more faster

Comment: There should be. But it's another question. Please write the actual code, benchmark it, then post it in a new question mentioning your tangible expectation

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
previous = " "
previousCount = 0
for words in sorted([ " ".join(key) for key in d ]) + [" "]:
    if words.startswith(previous):
        previousCount += 1
    else:
        print(previous,previousCount)
        if previousCount < 2 and previous != " ":
            del d[tuple(previous.split(" "))]
        previous = words
        previousCount = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

There must be more efficient (non `O(n^2)`) ways to do it, but this seems to be what you want:

```
input = {
    ('large','blue'): 4,
    ('cute','blue'): 3,
    ('large','blue','dog'): 2,
    ('cute','blue','dog'): 2,
    ('cute','blue','elephant'): 1,
}

keys = set(' '.join(k) for k in input)
filtered = {
    tuple(f.split())
    for f in keys
    if sum(f != k and f in k for k in keys) == 1
}
result = {k: v for k, v in input.items() if k not in filtered}

from pprint import pprint
pprint(sorted(result.items()))
```

Result:

```
[(('cute', 'blue'), 3),
 (('cute', 'blue', 'dog'), 2),
 (('cute', 'blue', 'elephant'), 1),
 (('large', 'blue', 'dog'), 2)]
```

The idea, from your requirements, is to identify the keys that appear *once* as part of other keys.

Answer (score 0):

You want to keep the 2-tuples that occur in more than one 3-tuple? I have a solution that loops over the 3s once to build a hashtable and then uses it to check for each 2 if it occurs in more than one 3.

Specifically occur means that they occur as substrings where the alphabet is words.

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter

d={('large','blue'):4,('cute','blue'):3,('large','blue','dog'):2,
  ('cute','blue','dog'):2,('cute','blue','elephant'):1}

# partition the tuple keys by length
tab = defaultdict(list)
for key in d:
    tab[len(key)].append(key)

# make counts of the 2-tuples in the 3-tuples
fil = Counter(v for key in tab[3] for v in [key[1:],key[:-1]])

# filter the 2-tuples that don't occur in more than one 3-tuple
tab[2] = [key for key in tab[2] if fil.get(key, 0) > 1]

[(' '.join(key), d[key]) for l in tab for key in tab[l]]
```

This results in:

```
[('cute blue', 3), ('large blue dog', 2), ('cute blue elephant', 1), ('cute blue dog', 2)]
```

Comment: it need not to be necessarily 2-3 tuple combination. And I have approx 250000 segments of varying length.

Comment: This can be generalized to work with longer tuples. It just requires starting with the highest length tuples and filtering the shorter.

Comment: Can you generalize this code for tuples starting from length 2 to 10. I'll mark this as answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
d = {('large', 'blue'): 4,
     ('cute', 'blue'): 3,
     ('large', 'blue', 'dog'): 2,
     ('cute', 'blue', 'dog'): 2,
     ('cute', 'blue', 'elephant'): 1}

final_list = [(' '.join(k), v) for k, v in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda kv: len(kv[0]))]
final = dict(final_list)
keys = [kv[0] for kv in final_list]

for idx, key in enumerate(keys):
    if sum(key in s for s in keys[idx + 1:]) == 1:
        del final[key]

print(final)

# {'cute blue': 3,
#  'large blue dog': 2,
#  'cute blue dog': 2,
#  'cute blue elephant': 1}
```

`final_list`, `final`, and `keys` are all essentially sorted versions of `d` (based on length). Then, look for "violating" elements of `keys` and delete the corresponding key in `final`.